# errors in sending a request tried, okhttp, httpurlconnection

Tags: android, httprequest, httpurlconnection, okhttp

Working on Android, Want to fetch a file, tried every tut on net- vogella/tutorialpoint/tutsplus/coursera/youtube.. but still not working

I copied the exact things in main activity and xml layout file from the tutorialspoint tutorial

[tutorials point tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.htm)

and still getting the errors...

I am unable to create a connection and fetch a single resonse from web, little help please !

Comment: and also added the permissions to the android manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got the answer now, I was starting the connection in the same Activity class.**

In android The Activity in which we initialize any View object than we can't start any task with that activity, We can say that activity is bound to the view, so for that, we have to use THREAD HANDLING. We can start the connection in a new Thread class and start that thread in our Activity or else we can USE ASYNC task.

Cheers !